# Upload File to Drive Remotely

Tags: google-drive-api

I was trying to upload files to google drive from a Desktop Application, but i couldnt find how to do it with Google Drive API since that is based for google browser apps. For this matter should i use Google Drive API or Documments API?

Answer (score 2):

You can use both Drive API or Documents List API to achieve, but the Drive API has the additional requirement that Apps need to be [installed](https://developers.google.com/drive/apps_overview#installing_a_drive_app) (for now) from the Chrome Web Store. Once installed, if you authorize the user with OAuth 2.0, you can use the Drive API in a desktop    app.

Comment: I was thinking about gData for java the problem is that it's not supported for android :/ The authentication on the gData is much more simple "DocsService client = new DocsService("lalala"); client.setUserCredentials("username", "password"); ". So there is no easy wait to auth on android? for a simple upload?

Comment: Your link is redirecting to a google-internal login page; do you have an external version you can link to?

Comment: @user1056053, ClientLogin has been [deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) as of April 20th. You should use OAuth 2.0 whenever possible. Also, the gdata-java-client library does work on Android (since version 1.47.0).